# Filtering of SQL Query using multiple ANDs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Big Query query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM tableE e
WHERE e.dateStart < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
AND e.dateEnd > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND TIMESTAMP_DIFF(endDate, startDate, DAY) > 7
LIMIT 1000;
```

and I am trying to get a list of events that started within a 7 day period and further filter out those events where the end date is AFTER 7 days of the start date.

However, when I run this query, I sometimes get results for events that happened in previous years (2011...2019).

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to re-write what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this using direct date comparisons:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM tableE e
WHERE e.dateStart < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AND
      e.dateStart > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
      e.dateEnd > TIMESTAMP_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
LIMIT 1000;
```

However, your issue is that the first two comparisons should both be on `dateStart`.

Note:  This assumes that `dateEnd` can be in the future.  Otherwise, you will get no rows.

Comment: Can you explain how your WHERE comparison is different from what I was trying to do?

I am brand new to SQL and still learning about all the ways WHERE and comparison clauses can be used

Comment: @babycoder . . . Primarily, it is comparing `dateStart` for the time comparison rather than mixing `dateStart` and `dateEnd`.